# Accessibility Issue Selecting Checkbox with Spacebar skips content

Tags: html, internet-explorer, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a dropdown with checkboxes, I am able to tab through the menu, get down into the dropdown and then select the checkbox with the spacebar. However, when I hit tab again the focus is now back to the top of the page and it should go to the next checkbox in the dropdown. This is only an issue in IE.

```
<label class="checkbox" tabindex="1" for="All Programs">
     <input name="programNameSelection" tabindex="1" id="All Programs" type="checkbox" checked="" value="All Programs">
     <span class="checkbox-text">All Programs</span> 
</label>
```

New Update

```
<label class="checkbox" for="All Programs">
     <input name="programNameSelection" tabindex="0" id="All Programs" type="checkbox" checked="" value="All Programs">
     <span class="checkbox-text">All Programs</span> 
</label>
```

Comment: why have you edited your question to show completely different code? It only makes it harder for people to help you bud.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I have updated to separate the code

Comment: Thats better! People need to see the history so they can rule out issues for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `tabindex=1` (twice).

If you are attempting to make items focusable you should be using `tabindex=0`.

Any positive integer on a tab index puts it in the tab order at the place specified and overrides the order of the DOM.

`tabindex=0` makes the item focusable, but in the order of the DOM.

For your example there should be no need for a `tabindex` at all if you put the input within a `form` as inputs are automatically focusable unless you override that feature (and putting it in a form helps with Screen Readers).

Also your `for` needs to be a single word, use `AllPrograms` with no space on both the `for` and on the input `id`

As a general rule (one I have never needed to break personally) there is no good reason to use a positive `tabindex` on an item, fix the order of the `HTML` elements instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just to clarify the tabbing works normally until I select one of the checkboxes in the dropdown list. I changed the tabIndex to zero and only put tabIndex on the Input control however still no luck. Everything works in order until I select the checkbox then it goes back up to the top

Comment: Double check you don't have a stray tabindex (try removing them all!), the only other possible cause is some JavaScript you haven't mentioned or that the checkbox is the last item in the tab order. Only other thought is that the page is refreshing on pressing space on the checkbox as it is submitting when it shouldn't?

Comment: I will try removing them all

Comment: I tried removing all the tab index but for some reason it still jumps up to the top, there must be something I am missing as this works perfectly for me in Chrome

Comment: I tracked the focus by using document.activeElement. After selecting the checkbox the focus switches from the checkbox to the body of the page. This may be the issue as the next tab would go to the first tabindex in the body.

Comment: yes that will be your issue. If there is nothing else focusable on that page it will jump back to the top.

Comment: just seen the site URL you gave, let me have a fiddle

Comment: Right, I don't know the exact cause but you have several errors in your JS showing in console. My guess is that when you click on a checkbox and it triggers the request to https://data.hrsa.gov/FindGrants/GetFindGrantDataBySection there is a misbehaving script that is causing some strange action. I tried observing the DOM for any minor transitions but the page is too complex for a StackOverflow 'help me out' amount of time I could spend investigating. Try looking at the error in `tools/find-grants` as I am guessing that is related to the ajax calls.

Comment: I found the issue, it was like you said there was another javascript function that uses the blur function to disregard the focus on the checkbox. thank you for your patience and help

Comment: Not a problem at all bud, that is one of those monster pages that is always going to bite you in the ass when things go wrong! Good luck with the rest of it!

Answer (score 1):

Although nesting the `<input/>` inside the `<label>` is theoretically standard and perfectly allowed, it is not recommanded, especially because it is known to cause issues with screen readers.

So my first advice before going further is to change your code for a more conventional one, where the `<label>` element is linked to the `<input/>` using the attributes `for` and `id`.
For the rest, it doesn't look bad at first glance.

Comment: Hey Thank you for the great suggestion, I tried it however I still have the same issue where after I select the checkbox, the next tab starts at the top of the page

Comment: Sorry to hijack this, but do you know which screen readers struggle with labels around inputs @QuentinC? Always great to learn something new I just never saw that on anything recent, I know it was an issue 5 years ago but the death of XP and ie8 was meant to resolve this. If it still the case then I will be updating my accessibility checklist!

Comment: It was especially the case with older jaws versions. I haven't retested with jaws 2019 to see if it has been fixed since, though. But htere are many old versions still around (including on XP) because updates aren't free of charge.

Comment: Cheers @QuentinC, learned something new and have adjusted my checklist accordingly! My fault for wrongly assuming the problem had gone away but after looking around I see there are still plenty of older screen readers in use!